# select a specific value in a drop down list options in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have a list of items(here model). one of the list item - PhoneNumber, i will load values of phoneNUmber from database. user can change the phone number from the dropdownlist. however when view is first loaded, users activephone number should be the selected option in dropdwonlist. users active phone number here is lp.PhoneNumber

i created a ViewData["PhoneNumber"] for @Html.DropDownList("PhoneNumber")

```
@foreach (var lp in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td class ="editor-field"><span class="SpaceForEditorField">@Html.EditorFor(order => lp.rKey)</span></td>
                <td class ="editor-field"><span class="SpaceForEditorField">@Html.EditorFor(order => lp.AccountName)</span></td>
                <td class ="editor-field"><span class="SpaceForEditorField">@Html.EditorFor(order => lp.AccountNumber)</span></td>
                <td class ="editor-field">
                    <span class="SpaceForEditorField">
                        @Html.DropDownList("PhoneNumber")                             
                    </span>                       
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

the code here is not displaying the active phone number as selected in dropdownlist, instead jus displays the items in dropdownlist.
i want to set the lp.PhoneNumber as selected item in the ddl "PhoneNumber"

i created ViewData["PhoneNumber"] in the controller  as below

```
public ActionResult LoadOrder(int id, string token)
        {
.....
.....

  ViewData["PhoneNumber"] =  new SelectList(new Ordering().GetPhoneNumberAvailableForOrder(id, token).ToList());

.......
.....
}
```

Comment: How do you create a `SelectList` of the phone numbers?

Comment: You have multiple problems here - please post your model and the signature of the POST method